# Git - Line specific Hash \ Tag

Tags: git, github, automation, gitlab, bitbucket

I've been assigned to a new task that requires use of Git in an unusual way.

I appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

The project requires:

1. Every individual line in a commit to have a unique Hash\Tag. (the
   Hashs\Tags will be used by an external-DB as a pointer and should
   remain un-changed)
2. The said Hash\Tag should Not change if there is a change in the
   Git-History and re-write of it.
3. A trigger\webhook to be triggered if there is a change in a certain
   line of code.

Example:

```
if (x === 0){              line-hash: 97553d8849553d8849551f [tag: vj20fhfiks]
   do something            line-hash: dd97553d853d8849551f19 [tag: vnw9sjjfjw]
}else{                     line-hash: 3d884951f198053d884955 [tag: 2j82jslsjf]
   do something else       line-hash: 804dd97553d8849598053d [tag: fh28sjs2jj]
}                          line-hash: f1980804dd975588495515 [tag: djs2ssjjsu]

----------------
commit-hash 58294c9d0bb8fdd97553d8849
Author: John Citizen
Date: 22/2/2020
----------------
```

I tried to keep the line count\index on each commit but that seems to be very un-reliable.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it with an example?

Comment: This is not a job for Git. You'll have to write this software yourself.